# What is the taper ratio approximately for the horizontal and vertical stabilizer of a fighter jet and what determines this taper ratio?

Tags: aircraft-design, horizontal-stabilizer, tail, vertical-stabilizer

I'm looking for historical taper ratios for the tails of different fighter aircrafts, or just a general fighter aircraft. Also why do fighter aircrafts want their taper ratio at a certain value. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

According to Aircraft Design by Raymer, taper ratios for the horizontal and vertical tail for fighters are generally 0.2-0.4 for both.